# Loading packages from separate document

Tags: packages, subfiles

I am using MikTeX and Texmaker to write in.

My issue is that we are a group of people writing the same report, and I want to load the packages we are using from a separate file, or a similar method.

My main document that I am running looks like this:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}  %Grafiske ting

\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{psfrag}

\usepackage{color, colortbl} %SKAL STÅ FØR LISTINGS
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{a4wide}   %Smalle marginer
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %Latin tegn
%\usepackage[Danish]{babel}  % æ ø å %Sætter overskrifter engelsk

\usepackage{booktabs, multicol, multirow}  %Multirows osv i tabeller
\usepackage{fixltx2e}  %excel til latex


\usepackage{subfig}  %Flere figurer
\usepackage{float}   %Gør det muligt at placere figurene det rigtige sted.
\usepackage{subfloat}

\usepackage{amsmath}  %Math - Align osv.
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{table}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Matlab}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\newcommand{\vis}[1]{\textit{\citeauthor{#1}, \citeyear{#1}} \cite{#1}}
\usepackage{cleveref}



\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{0mm}
       {-\baselineskip}{0.1\baselineskip}{\bfseries\large}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{0mm}%
       {-\baselineskip}{0.1\baselineskip}{\bfseries\normalsize}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{0mm}%
     {-\baselineskip}{0.1\baselineskip}{\bfseries\small}}
\makeatother

\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-5pt}
\parindent=0pt
\parskip=1.0ex

\newcommand{\topspace}{\vrule height 15pt width 0pt}

\newcommand{\notetitle}[4]{
    \begin{center}
      {\Large \bf #1}  \\[9pt]
      {\Large \bf #2}  \\[12pt]
      {\large #3}  \\[6pt]
      {\normalsize #4}  \\[36pt]
    \end{center}}



\input{T/Frontpage.tex}  
%\input{T/Abstract.tex}      
%\input{T/Commandoes_Figures.tex}
%\input{T/Commandoes_Math.tex}
%\input{T/Commandoes_Other.tex}
%\input{T/Commandoes_Tables.tex}
\input{T/Preface.tex}
\input{T/Introduction.tex}
%\input{T/Part1.tex}
%\input{T/Part2.tex}
%\input{T/Part3.tex}
\input{T/Part4.tex}
%\input{T/Part5.tex}
%\input{T/Part6.tex}
%\input{T/Part7.tex}
%\input{T/Part8.tex}
%\input{T/Part9.tex}
%\input{T/Part10.tex}
\input{T/Conclusion.tex}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{bibtex}

%\input{T/Appendix.tex}

\end{document}
```

Now everyone has their own main file and can thereby run only the parts of the report, that they are working with. 
What I want to do is to have one main file where all the packages and such loaded before the begin document part, are put in, so that if one person wants to add another package, everyone won't have to change this.

If this is a completely ridiculous way of doing it, alternative solutions would be most welcome as well. The main purpose of doing it this way is that everyone can write independently of each other, but are still able to see what everyone else is writing.

Hope the question is clarified properly.

Comment: `a4wide` is a deprecated package, and also `\bf` is deprecated.

Comment: From your question I gather you have the subfiles in a central location. You could create a `myconfig.sty` file, in the same central location and insert there all the `\usepackage{whatchacallit}` calls and any other global options/definitions. In your main file you would have this one only, i.e. `\usepackage{myconfig}`.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make your documents all look like

```
\documentclass{mylocal}
\begin{document}
\input{T/Frontpage}
...
\end{document}
```

Then share a `mylocal.cls` file that looks like

```
\LoadClass[11pt]{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}

\usepackage{graphicx}  %Grafiske ting

\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{psfrag}

\usepackage{color, colortbl} %SKAL STÅ FØR LISTINGS
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{a4wide}   %Smalle marginer
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %Latin tegn
%\usepackage[Danish]{babel}  % æ ø å %Sætter overskrifter engelsk

\usepackage{booktabs, multicol, multirow}  %Multirows osv i tabeller
\usepackage{fixltx2e}  %excel til latex


\usepackage{subfig}  %Flere figurer
\usepackage{float}   %Gør det muligt at placere figurene det rigtige sted.
\usepackage{subfloat}

\usepackage{amsmath}  %Math - Align osv.
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{table}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Matlab}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\newcommand{\vis}[1]{\textit{\citeauthor{#1}, \citeyear{#1}} \cite{#1}}
\usepackage{cleveref}



\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{0mm}
       {-\baselineskip}{0.1\baselineskip}{\bfseries\large}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{0mm}%
       {-\baselineskip}{0.1\baselineskip}{\bfseries\normalsize}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{0mm}%
     {-\baselineskip}{0.1\baselineskip}{\bfseries\small}}
\makeatother

\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-5pt}
\parindent=0pt
\parskip=1.0ex

\newcommand{\topspace}{\vrule height 15pt width 0pt}

\newcommand{\notetitle}[4]{
    \begin{center}
      {\Large \bf #1}  \\[9pt]
      {\Large \bf #2}  \\[12pt]
      {\large #3}  \\[6pt]
      {\normalsize #4}  \\[36pt]
    \end{center}}
```

Comment: Also `\ProvidesClass{mylocal}[YYYY/MM/DD vX.Y My local class]` can be added including version date `YYYY/MM/DD` and number `X.Y` that also will appear in `\listfiles`' file list and that will make it easier to identify the latest version of the class.

Answer (score 1):

`\input` also works in the preamble. You can create a formatsAndDefs.tex file in your working dir that includes all the lines of your preamble and use `\input{formatsAndDefs}` just before your `\begin{document}`.

The formatsAndDefs.tex file would look like:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}  %Grafiske ting

\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{psfrag}

\usepackage{color, colortbl} %SKAL STÅ FØR LISTINGS
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{a4wide}   %Smalle marginer
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %Latin tegn
%\usepackage[Danish]{babel}  % æ ø å %Sætter overskrifter engelsk

\usepackage{booktabs, multicol, multirow}  %Multirows osv i tabeller
\usepackage{fixltx2e}  %excel til latex


\usepackage{subfig}  %Flere figurer
\usepackage{float}   %Gør det muligt at placere figurene det rigtige sted.
\usepackage{subfloat}

\usepackage{amsmath}  %Math - Align osv.
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{table}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Matlab}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\newcommand{\vis}[1]{\textit{\citeauthor{#1}, \citeyear{#1}} \cite{#1}}
\usepackage{cleveref}
```

And your main file like this (in your dir structure):

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\input{T/formatsAndDefs.tex}

\begin{document}
%insert your \include or \input chapters here
\end{document}
```

Also, you may want to take a look at this [topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include) and might consider switching your `\input` commands in the main document (i.e. between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`) to `\include` commands.

Though a bit slower, they offer the advantage of swithcing only one command to `\includeonly`, so that the compilation focuses only on the chapter you are working on.

Comment: Note that, usually, we don't include the `.tex` extension when dealing with `\input` and friends.

Comment: Thanks alot for the awesome suggestions.
End up using David Carlisle's file setup and it worked flawlessly!
As for the include i might consider it, however as i read it, there is a pagebreak before and after the include parts, and this is not always a good thing in my case. I Might not allways want that.

Thanks.